# Add function won't work on database

Tags: php, mysql, database, function, addition

Hello everyone I'm studying php + html this semester and I got stuck on this code.
Everything works (list + delete from db) but adding for some reason won't add to the db even though it does validate the inputs and give the code number at the end of URL using the header function. Yes I did include the page that addProduct function at :)

here is the code if anyone can give me an advice or hint

PHP Code:

```
if ( $action == 'add_product' ) {
  $code = $_POST['code'];
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $version = $_POST['version'];
  $releaseDate = $_POST['releaseDate'];

  if (empty($code) || empty($name)  || empty($version) || empty($releaseDate)) {
    $error = "Please enter a valid and correct values.";
    include('../errors/error.php');
    exit();
  } else {
    addProduct($code, $name, $version, $releaseDate);
    header("Location: .?code=$code");
  }
}
```

here is the addProduct function

```
function addProduct($code, $name, $version, $releaseDate){
  global $db;

  $query = "INSERT INTO products
              (productCode, name, version, releaseDate)
            VALUES
              ('$code', '$name', '$version' '$releaseDate')";
  $db->exec($query);
}
```

and this is the HTML Code

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_product"/>
    <label>Code:</label> <input type="input" name="code"/>
    <br />
    <label>Name:</label><input type="input" name="name"/>
    <br />
    <label>Version:</label><input type="input" name="version"/>
    <br />
    <label>Release Date:</label><input type="input" name="releaseDate"/> <label>Use 'yyyy-mm-dd' format</label>
    <br />
    <label>&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Product" />
    <br />  <br />
</form>
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it just me or you are missing a comma here in your function?

`VALUES ('$code', '$name', '$version' '$releaseDate')";`

Comment: OMG thank you so much I've been working on this for 2 days and everything is working but no new values added to the DB

Thank you so much mate!

Answer (score 0):

You may use mysql_query($query); instead of $db->exec($query);

Comment: I used $db = new PDO() and query is for SELECT not INSERT
beside I tried to use query doesn't work
BTW first php and html codes are in the same page
I didn't use multiple pages